# Mute all <audio> elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

### Description of Problem ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5z4h/)):

I'm attempting to iterate over all  elements on a page and mute them with jQuery. Does jQuery just not play nice with HTML5 audio or is there a better approach?

### Code:

```
$('#sound1').click(function() {
    var sound1 = new Audio();
    sound1.src = "http://sounddogs.com/previews/4006/mp3/209105_SOUNDDOGS__up.mp3"
    sound1.play();
});

$('#sound2').click(function() {
    var sound2 = new Audio();
    sound2.src = "http://sounddogs.com/previews/4023/mp3/210622_SOUNDDOGS__do.mp3"
    sound2.play();
});

$('#mute').click(function() {
    $('audio').each(function(i) {
        this.volume = 0;
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't append the elements to the DOM. So `$('audio')` retunes an empty collection.

Comment: I see that now, thank you. But is there just no way to iterate through JavaScript audio objects and mute all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `volume` control on played music objets something like this

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c5z4h/7/)

**Update**

You can create the array `tracks[]` and store the played audios into this, and and mute all this audios when clicked on mute. something like this.

```
var tracks = [];
$('#sound1').click(function() {
    sound1 = new Audio();
    sound1.src = "http://sounddogs.com/previews/4006/mp3/209105_SOUNDDOGS__up.mp3"
    sound1.play();
    tracks.push(sound1);
});

$('#sound2').click(function() {
     sound2 = new Audio();
    sound2.src = "http://sounddogs.com/previews/4023/mp3/210622_SOUNDDOGS__do.mp3"
    sound2.play();
    tracks.push(sound2);
});

$('#mute').click(function() {
    for(var i=0; i<tracks.length; i++){
        tracks[i].volume = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but how would I go about iterating through all the JS objects without specifying them each specifically?

Comment: Superb. This is precisely what I was seeking. Well done!